# Simple BigQuery Join Error Using Stitch for Shopify Integration

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, left-join

Wrote the following in BigQuery using the Stitch data integration to pull in tables from Shopify. Pretty straightforward but I'm unfamiliar with nesting, which I suspect may be throwing my query off.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Query and error below:

Query

```
SELECT distinct
order_number
,so.created_at
,buyer_accepts_marketing
,currency
,value. sku
,value. vendor
,value. variant_title
,value. gift_card
,value. product_id
,customer. id
,shipping_address. province
,shipping_address. country
,shipping_address. city
,shipping_address. longitude
,shipping_address. country_code
,shipping_address. latitude
,sum(total_price_usd) as price_usd
,sum(total_price) as total_price
,sum(total_discounts) as total_discounts
FROM `shopifytest-272721.testconn.orders` as so
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(line_items)

left join

(SELECT distinct
created_at
,id
,product_type
,title
,value.sku
,value.fulfillment_service
,value.inventory_quantity
FROM `shopifytest-272721.testconn.products` 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(variants)) as sp 

on so.product_id = sp.id 
and so.created_at = sp.created_at

group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
```

Error
**Name product_id not found inside so at [36:7]**

Comment: doubt we can answer this without having sample data / schema - please add to your question

Answer (score 0):

In the first select you have `value.product_id` but you are joining on `so.product_id = sp.id`, the field `product_id` is not known at this level, but it could work if you set the alias:

```
value.product_id as product_id
```

Another field that is noisy is `so.created_at` in the first query. Let me suggest the following structure for your query:

```
SELECT distinct
order_number
,created_at
,buyer_accepts_marketing
,currency
,value. sku
,value. vendor
,value. variant_title
,value. gift_card
,value. product_id as product_id
,customer. id
,shipping_address. province
,shipping_address. country
,shipping_address. city
,shipping_address. longitude
,shipping_address. country_code
,shipping_address. latitude
,sum(total_price_usd) as price_usd
,sum(total_price) as total_price
,sum(total_discounts) as total_discounts
FROM `shopifytest-272721.testconn.orders` as so --if line_items is contained into so:
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(so.line_items) as items

left join

(SELECT distinct
created_at
,id
,product_type
,title
,value.sku
,value.fulfillment_service
,value.inventory_quantity
FROM `shopifytest-272721.testconn.products` as p
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(p.variants)) as sp 

on items.product_id = sp.id 
and items.created_at = sp.created_at

group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
```

Additionally, as you are not familiar with nesting I would recommend you check [UNNEST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest), [Flattening arrays](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays), [Join Types](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Join-Types_132067691).